# Compiler No Longer Allows Access to Private Members of Type Variables

Tags: java, private, specifications

According to the documentation http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html Java 7 prevents access to members of private type variables. The example given is:

```
class A {
   private int val = 42;
}

class Test<X extends A> {
    void test(X x) {
        int i = x.val; //error in JDK 7
    }
}
```

I wonder why this behaviour makes any sense, since using the following "workaround", access to the private member can be achieved, just by using standard language features:

```
class A {
    private int val = 42;
}

class Test<X extends A> {
    void test(X x) {
        final A a = x;          
        int i = a.val; // works in Java 7
    }
}
```

Shielding access to the private fields would make sense if access were shielded via all paths, but just using a simple intermediate assignment bypasses the shielded path. Does that make any sense? What might have been the rationale? Or this is a bug in the Java 7 spec?

Comment: Have you tried compiling the above code? Why would it compile? `val` is private. private variables are not accessible from outside the class, and have never been.

Comment: So to be clear, your question is why the first example is prohibited even in those cases where the second example would compile (such as when A and Test are both members of the same parent class)?

Comment: The only way I can see your second code block working is if class Test is an inner class of A.

Comment: I too believe "val" must not be visible and you will definitely get compilation error.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yes, the code compiles if A and Test are members of a common class. You can try via this project:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35235455/java7compat.zip

Comment: However an even clearer example of the issue is this class:

`public class A<T extends A<T>> {
 
     private final int value;
 
       public A(T t) {
     final A a = t;
     this.value = a.value;
     }

    }`

Comment: Class A should have access to its own private member variables, even if accessed via a different instance. Java 7 blocks access via the type T which is a subclass of A (in java 6 it was possible to write this.value = t.value). Using the simple intermediate assignment of type T to type A (which is guaranteed to work) it is possible to overcome the restriction, though.
To me it feels as though it should not be possible to circumvent an access rule by just using an alternative syntax. This in turn suggests that the rule itself does not make much sense.